# Bootstrap Navbar Logo not found

Tags: python, html, django

Hello I am trying to get my NavBar on bootstrap to show a Logo, I have tried moving the png to different folders in the app but I get this error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 21, 2022 - 18:18:54
Django version 4.0.1, using settings 'mapproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[21/Jan/2022 18:19:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 229230
Not Found: /logo.png
[21/Jan/2022 18:19:00] "GET /logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2219
```

Here is the index.html:

```
  <!--Navbar-->
<!-- Just an image -->
<!-- Image and text -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"">
    <img src="logo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""/>
    EtherWAN Product Map
  </a>
</nav>
<!--End Navbar-->
```

Comment: show your file structure. I know in flask you have to put the image in a "static" folder.

Answer (score 1):

"static" folders are needed in Django like in flask. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

put your image in the static folder and call: **static/logo.png** instead of **logo.png**.

file structure:

[image]

HTML File Code Example:

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
 <!--Navbar-->
 <!-- Just an image -->
 <!-- Image and text -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"">
   <img src="{% static 'posts/images/logo.png' %}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""/>
EtherWAN Product Map
</a>
</nav>
<!--End Navbar-->    
{% endblock content %}
```

the file structure can be mainapp/ -> static/ -> images/ logo.png