# How can I resolve the 404 error in the product page here?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I'm making a website with a store. It looks like this: store -> catalog -> all products - > single product. When I going to a page with a single product, i get 404 error.

**views.py**

```
def product_view(request: WSGIRequest, product_slug: str):
try:
    product = (
        Product.objects
            .prefetch_related('productimage_set')
            .filter(slug=product_slug)
            .first()
    )
    is_in_cart = CartProduct.objects.filter(
       product=product,
       cart__user=request.user,
       cart__active=True).first()
    context = {
      'product': product,
    # 'is_in_cart': is_in_cart,
   }
except Product.DoesNotExist:
   raise Http404
return render(
   request, 'shop/product.html',
   context)

def category_list(request: WSGIRequest, category_slug: str):
try:
    category: Category = (
        Category.objects
            .prefetch_related("product_set")
            .get(slug=category_slug))
except Category.DoesNotExist:
   raise Http404
return render(
   request, 'shop/category.html',
   {"category": category})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('', views.CatalogList.as_view(), name='shop'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_list, name='category'),
path('<slug:product_slug>/', views.product_view, name='product')
```

**base urls**

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('shop/', include('page.shop.urls')),
```

**templates**
[image]

**models.py**
[image]

Comment: Django uses static files for images and css. see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70810499/5954452

Comment: If you run that `Products.objects.filter(...)` code in a django manage.py shell, what results do you get?

Comment: i get **Page not found (404)**

Comment: Can you please share the models.py ...?

Comment: I  added photo models.py in the question

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the try except part of your view is taking you there because it is not finding that Product object.  John Gordon's comment would give you a way to find this out, but it is not run in the browser, nor would it produce a 404 error.  Here's how to do what he is suggesting.  Run the following in your terminal:

```py
python manage.py shell
```

Then when the shell prompt opens run:

```py
print(Product.objects.prefetch_related('productimage_set').filter(slug=product_slug))
```

Here is another way to do it without the shell:

```py
def product_view(request: WSGIRequest, product_slug: str):

    # First see if product_slug is what you expect it to be:
    print('product_slug = ', product_slug)

    try:
        product = (
            Product.objects
                .prefetch_related('productimage_set')
                .filter(slug=product_slug)
                .first()
        )

        # Now check to see if django is finding any Product object with your filters:
        print(product)

        is_in_cart = CartProduct.objects.filter(
           product=product,
           cart__user=request.user,
           cart__active=True).first()
        context = {
          'product': product,
        # 'is_in_cart': is_in_cart,
       }
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
       # If the product is not found (None) then your code takes you here
       raise Http404
    return render(
       request, 'shop/product.html',
       context)
```

If as I suspect this is what's going on, then You can troubleshoot the Product model, and how the product_slug is being obtained.  For that I would need to see your `models.py` as well as the `product.html` template (the template you provide does not show any links/buttons that would take you to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `Python manage.py shell` shows  NameError: name 'Product' is not defined.

Comment: Please add code, not images of code. Did you try my other suggestion of using print in your views.py?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I tried your second suggestion, i completed  commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. And after the launch I got an error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Unfortunately, I can't add the code to the question, because writing me that too much code has been added.

Comment: Are you running the server with `python manage.py runserver`?  You can try to run `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`, where mysite is the name of your project, but you shouldn't need to do this if using the standard way of running django with `python manage.py runserver`.  You might want to edit your question with your `settings.py`.